Windows Server 2012 + COM to Send Mail Times Out
I know this is old stuff, but I am really just trying to get things working again after being forced to move to a new VPS.  I have some classic ASP pages.  They use a COM object (Persits).  I did install the 64-bit version.  I also tried using a different COM object.  At first, I was getting errors about the component not registering (32-bit version).  I tried a couple other things and also switched to the 64-bit version.  I do not get a 500 Internal Server error anymore (and the resulting error in logs).  Instead, I am getting a timeout.  What's weird is that I am getting a timeout with a different COM component too.  Any ideas on a solution?  Thanks much for any insight.  I am not looking to reinvent the wheel here.  Just looking to get the sites fixed quickly at this point.  TYVM.
Trying to send email from Classic ASP.  Getting errors.

Show the code.  Show the errors.  Persists is decent with their products so there is probably an issue somewhere.   Try to send email manually just using Asp Classic like this as a test to see if it also fails-- >
https://www.w3schools.com/ASp/asp_send_email.asp

Could it be old enough that the email standard changed since the original system was deployed?  Such as it was CDOS long ago but since then CDONTs has come out to replace it.  Most situations I have seen where the email fails its cause its the original script from 20 years ago and not something that has been updated in the last decade or so to be compatible with the newer system.  Also of note, if you are using a paid host, their standards change too, thus it might of worked, but now they too use the new system, so you must upgrade.
